# How do you access return statements in the Mist UI

Tags: solidity, web3js, mist

If I have a contract and its interface added to Mist and I call a function, how do I access its return statement?

Answer (score 2):

the functions, which are static should have the `constant: true` in the son interface, then the wallet will show them on the left side automatically.
Transactions send to a contract function can't have return values, you would need to fire logs for this. But the wallet currently does show logs of contracts...